# Not able to call PowerShell from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have this PowerShell that I usually call like this :

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\tmp\getmember2.ps1" -groupnames "ABC"
```

Now, I need to call this from my nodejs. So, this is what I create :

```
    var spawn = Meteor.npmRequire("child_process").spawn;
    child = spawn("powershell.exe",["-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File d:\\tmp\\getmember2.ps1 -groupnames \"ABC\""]);
    child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
         console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
    });
    child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
         console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    });
    child.on("exit",function(){
         console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    });

    child.stdin.end();
```

However I am getting this error :

```
    I20170222-16:58:25.257(8)? API started
    I20170222-16:58:26.175(8)? Powershell Errors: At line:1 char:2
    I20170222-16:58:26.174(8)?
    I20170222-16:58:26.175(8)?     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError:    (-:String)
    [], ParentContainsErrorR
    I20170222-16:58:26.175(8)? + - <<<< ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File    d:\tmp\getmember2.ps1
    I20170222-16:58:26.176(8)? Powershell Errors:    ecordException
    I20170222-16:58:26.176(8)? Powershell Errors:     +  FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
    I20170222-16:58:26.176(8)? Powershell Errors:
    I20170222-16:58:26.177(8)?
    I20170222-16:58:26.174(8)? Powershell Errors: Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
    I20170222-16:58:26.259(8)? Powershell Script finished
```

Any idea on why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change my code to use child_process.exec() instead of spawn(). 
As described in this [link](https://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html) :

> Spawn is best used to when you want the child process to return a large amount of data to Node - image processing, reading binary data etc. Use exec to run programs that return result statuses, instead of data.

Code changed to below and run my powershell neatly.

```
  var child = exec('Powershell.exe  -executionpolicy ByPass  -File d:\\tmp\\getmember.ps1 -processdir d:\\temp -groupnames "ABC"', 
    function(err, stdout, stderr){
      //callback(err)
      if(err){
        console.error(err);
      }else {
        console.log("should be no issue"); 
      }
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        // Print out what being printed in the powershell
        console.log(data);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        //print error being printed in powershell
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);

    });

    child.on('close',function(code){
      // To check the result of powershell exit code
      console.log("exit code is "+code);
      if(code==0)
      {
         console.log("Powershell run successfully, exit code = 0 ")
      }else {
         console.log("ERROR, powershell exited with exit code = "+ code);
      }
    });

    child.stdin.end();
```